# How to add SSL Certificate Chain to TrustStore jks file with Javacode

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, addition, truststore

I have to write a java code in order to add to TrustStore CA Certificate and Session Certificate without Private Key. Ich have code that can add Private Key and Certificate Chain to Key Store, but it's not possible to add they without Private Key to Trust Store. There ist a code that add Certificateschain and Private Key to Key Store:

```
public static void writeKeyStoreFile(String keyStoreFileName, String password, String alias, PrivateKey privateKey,Certificate... certificates) {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        final KeyStore ks = readKeyStore(keyStoreFileName, password);
        /*
         * If keystore is of type {@code jks} {@code key} must be encoded as
         * {@code EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo}
         */
        ks.setKeyEntry(alias, privateKey, password.toCharArray(), certificates);// certificates - welche Certificate wo eingesetzt wird?

        System.out.println("keyStoreFileName fuer pushKey2Cert: " + keyStoreFileName);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(keyStoreFileName));
        ks.store(fos, password.toCharArray());
        fos.flush();
    } catch (final Exception e) {// nur warn!!!
        throw new RuntimeException(KEYSTORE_FEHLER + "bei pushKey2Cert in " + keyStoreFileName + " / Alias " + alias
                + " / Passwort *****", e);
    } finally {
        if (fos != null) {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(KEYSTORE_FEHLER + "bei pushKey2Cert in  " + keyStoreFileName
                        + " / Alias " + alias + " / Passwort *****", e);
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

If anyone has a good idea I'd appreciate a good answer.

Comment: Use [KeyStore.setCertificateEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/KeyStore.html#setCertificateEntry(java.lang.String,java.security.cert.Certificate)). The documentation of a Java library class contains information about that class, and thus is a good place to look for information about that class that is useful if you want to use that class for something. Note while PrivateKeyEntry can contain a chain of certs, each TrustedCertEntry contains only one, although Java never needs more than one cert from a chain in the truststore to validate.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hint! I tried to use instead of:

ts.setKeyEntry(alias, privateKey, password.toCharArray(), certificates); 
the line with setCertificateEntry() and it works:

ts.setCertificateEntry(alias, certificates[0]);